How much space does Node.js take?
To use React, I recently downloaded and installed Node.js. After the installation I noticed that it took more than 10gb in my C:\drive. Unfortunately I don't have much storage left in C:\drive. Is it the overall actual size? Will it also get bigger over time?
During the installation I selected "automatically install the necessary tools" which includes chocolatey. It also installed python. But I still couldn't understand why it took up almost 12gb of my storage.

Can you use a tool like TreeSize to get a more detailed idea of where the high disk-space usage is, whether the files have been added recently and whether they look related to Node?

I'll give it a try. Thank you
